# How can we extract the prosecution history for the reexamination?

Tags: patent-applications, office-action, prosecution, reexamination

The patent US7405443 has been reexamined but the corresponding office action is missing from the file wrapper as well as global dossier.

Answer (score 1):

To find a reexamination record look up the patent application for the issued patent in [Public PAIR](https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair).

Under the Continuity tab will be a list of child applications (if any) and reexaminations (if any).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When there is a reexamination the prosecution would be done under a new application, Please look for the prosecution history of the reexamination under the application number  90/011,079 it's has the prosecution history.

Comment: How did you get this application number?

Comment: If you describe how you got this information, then the question becomes useful for other patents too.

Comment: when its a reexamination the prosecution would be done under a new application , i just looked for the new application number in PAIR.

Comment: @RishiM_IPR Please add this info to the answer. The idea is to make the answer as useful as possible and not to assume a reader will look at the comments too.